# List index out of range error in nested lists. Python 3.4

Tags: python, list

I have created a nested list which is 10 lists each containing 10 more lists. I want to be able to insert a value into the nested list at a given position.

When I run this program it says `list index out of range` on `board.insert([5][2],  1)`, line 13. I tried to put `board.insert(board[5][2],  1)`, but it then takes the value in 5, 2 which is 0 and inserts the number 1 in position 0. I'm using python 3.4.

```
board = [   
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
 [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
 ]
board.insert([5][2],  1)
```

Comment: Did you really mean insert, or *set*? Inserting will add another value to the list, growing it by one element. I think you want to set instead, replacing the current `0` value with `1`.

Comment: For clarity, the `IndexError` is being thrown on `board.insert([5][2], 1)` because `[5][2]` tells python to access the index-2 element of `[5]` which only has an index-0 element.  It is not coming from `insert`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the "coordinates" as parameter to insert. You have to do it like this:

```
board[5].insert(2, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
board[5][2] = 1
```

This creates a board that looks like this:

```
[   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

The problem with `insert` is that it will add another value to the list. The solution provided by Klaus would produce a table that looks like this. Notice the extra element in `board[5]`:

```
[   [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Comment: I would normally use del() to remove the element and then insert a new element with insert().